# Deleting a many-to-many relationship object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a web server where I serve User objects through a REST API.

Recently I've added the option for users to create Groups. Groups have a Name, a Color (represented as an int), an Owner (User object reference), and Members.

The Members property is a many-to-many relationship. One User can be member of multiple Groups, and one Group may have multiple members.

However I'm having problems with the removal of Groups. I want to give the Owner user the option to delete a Group - thus, removing all members, and removing the reference to the Group itself.

However I'm getting the following error upon trying to delete it:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_GroupUser_Group\". The conflict occurred in database \"database\", table \"dbo.GroupUser\", column 'Groups_Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.
```

I'm using the following code to remove the Group:

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    group.Owner.OwnedGroups.Remove(group);
    group.Owner = null;
    db.Groups.Remove(group);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message says you have a conflict with the REFERENCE constraint `FK_GroupUser_Group`. It seems the group still have users, though the group does not have an owner anymore (since you deleted it). Try clearing the users association:

```
group.Users.Clear()‌​
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Cascade Delete option**

Cascade delete allows dependent data to be automatically deleted when the principal record is deleted. If you delete a Destination, for example, the related Lodgings will also be deleted automatically. `Entity Framework supports cascade delete behavior` for in-memory data as well as in the database. it is recommended that you implement cascade delete on entities in the model if their mapped database objects also have cascade delete defined.

**Database First Approach**

Cascade delete defined in a database constraint as,

[image]

**Code First Approach**

```
HasRequired(l=>l.OwnedGroups).WithMany(d=>d.Groups)  
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true)

HasRequired(l=>l.Groups).WithMany(d=>d.Users)  
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it is an older project using Model First (lots of headaches especially with updates to the model layer - always have to deploy locally and diff with live server to create a patch).

Answer (score 0):

You must apply `ON DELETE CASCADE`, to let the system delete the related data.

Answer (score 0):

use .WillCascadeOnDelete(true) or Include

WillCascadeOnDelete:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
  .HasMany<Child>(c => c.Children)
  .WithOptional(x => x.Parent)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

use Include

```
  var adv = db.Adv.Include(b => b.Features)
                  .Include(b => b.AdvDetails)
                  .Include(b => b.AdvGallery)
                  .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
  db.Adv.Remove(adv);
```

> for .HasMany(...).WithMany(...) Include is ok